# How to get id from jsp page to servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, servlets

I have a list of users registered on a website and when the admin clicks to approve, it must fetch the id and then move that row to another table called login... now the problem here is from jsp how to fetch id in servlet so that it can be passed into a method to service and DAO layers.

Below is my jsp:

```
<tr bgcolor="white">
<td><b>id</b></td>
<td><b>FirstName</b></td>
<td><b>LastName</b></td>
<td><b>Gender</b></td>
<td><b>Category</b></td>
<td><b>DateOfBirth</b></td>
<td><b>Age</b></td>
<td><b>Address</b></td>
<td><b>Country</b></td>
<td><b>State</b></td>
<td><b>City</b></td>
<td><b>PinCode</b></td>
<td><b>EmailId</b></td>
<td><b>ContactNo</b></td>
<td><b>MobileNo</b></td>
</tr>


 <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client">
 <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${client.id}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.firstName}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.lastName}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.gender}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.category}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.date}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.age}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.address}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.country}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.state}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.city}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.pinCode}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.emailId}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.contactNo}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${client.mobileNo}"/></td>
            <td><a href="ClientApproveServlet?id=${client.id}">APPROVE</a></td> // I have fetched the id here
            <td><a href="Reject.jsp">REJECT</a></td>
            <td><a href="OnHold.jsp">ONHOLD</a></td>

            </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

Stack TRace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at com.affiliate.DAO.ClientApproveDAO.insertClient(ClientApproveDAO.java:28)
    at com.affiliate.service.ClientApproveService.clientApprove(ClientApproveService.java:12)
    at com.affiliate.servlet.ClientApproveServlet.doGet(ClientApproveServlet.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at com.affiliate.DAO.ClientApproveDAO.insertClient(ClientApproveDAO.java:23)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Id is not a number, hence throwing number format exception. Check if the value of Id is number.

Comment: I didnt get your prepared statement?What type `insert` query is that?with no values in it

Comment: hey you should check user model naming the datatype in string or int.

Comment: @jmail can u pls elaborate it i didnt get u??

Comment: hey @user3222718 check my answer for user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i resolved it changing my DAO like this:

```
public class ClientApproveDAO {

        private DataSource dataSource;
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement statement=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    public void insertClient(int id) {    
        try{
            conn=dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            ps.executeUpdate("insert into login(id,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)select * from register where id="+id+"");
            ps.setInt(1, id);

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
            if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }


    }

}
```

Thank you all for all the help and this is my final code its working absolutely fine and as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between `$` and `{client.id}`

```
<a href="ClientApproveServlet?id= $ {client.id}">
                                   ↑
```

Should be

```
<a href="ClientApproveServlet?id=${client.id}">
```

### Update

It means that we overcame NumberFormat. Now, error is in insertClient() method.

I can say from exception your syntax of insert statement is wrong.

Just add the condition `where id=?`, because `select * from register` fetch all the records.

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(id,FirstName,
     LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,
     PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)select * from register where id=?");
ps.setInt(1, id);
```

Comment: Now this exception occurs:Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: @user3222718 : It means that we overcame `NumberFormat`. Now, error is in `insertClient()` method

Comment: yes i removed where clause as well i have editted the question pls have a look and help me...

Comment: check again. it should be more like `insert into login (id) values (?)`. then  `ps.setInt(1, id);`

Comment: this is the exception am getting on adding where clause :  **java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1**

Comment: I did as u said in **UPDATE** its giving exception as above

Comment: @Aniket Kulkarni we were almost there but u stopped posting pls help me in fixing this

Comment: @Aniket Kulkarni **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1**

Comment: @user3222718 : this does not provide enough information to solve your problem. Please post stack trace

Comment: @AniketKulkarni please find the stack trace on the top where the question is posted

Answer (score 0):

Just check your SQL query. My point of view your column count are not matching. Try to give like

```
select id,firstname... etc
```

instead of

```
select * from tablename
```

Comment: if so then how can it move the whole table correctly under the proper column names... I dont think so this would be the problem. :-(

Comment: use like thisPreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(id,FirstName,
     LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,
     PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)select id,firstname,lastname from register where id=?");
ps.setInt(1, id);

Comment: **Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1** am getting this error on doing wat u said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a space in $ {client.id} just remove it will work.

```
 <a href="ClientApproveServlet?id= ${client.id}">
```

I think you query also not well formatted try:

```
 String query ="insert into login(id,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,"
 " Address,Country,State,city,PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)"+
 " select id,..,..,.. FROM register; ";
```

Comment: ya i did thank u ... I have editted the question please have a look i deleted the space as well as where clause in my insert query... But not getting the desired output yet

Comment: where does your insert statement add values?

Answer (score 0):

you must change insert code following as:

```
insert into login (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,

                     Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,PinCode,

                     EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

you should check this user model like as:

```
private int userid;
public int getUserid()
{
return userid;  
}
public void setUserid(int userid)
{
this.userid=userid; 
}
```

you should change this type for your insert type:

```
public void addUser(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into users (firstname,lastname,dob,email)values(?,?,?,?)");

            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getDob().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: and for the SQL Query its throwing SQL Syntax error

Comment: ur answer seems more legit den d others.Others dont even have values for thier insert statement

Comment: @user3222718 do u already have the record in d database table or are you creating a new record  by inserting?cause you could easily use update.

Comment: am trying to insert data from one table to another and am new to this spring mvc so finding it difficult

Comment: @user3222718 so y do u need id if it is a new record?

Comment: @user211 please read the question in the top... when i click accept for a particular user his data and only his data should be moved to login table from register....

Comment: yes i got ur point..but since it is a new table and a new record u can just insert it into the table along with the primary key id of the record from the old table..

Comment: hey @user3222718, if you don't mine, please show me exact error.

Comment: @user3222718 u mean to say manually like `"insert into login(id,firstname,...)select id,firstname,.... from register"` is it soo?

Comment: @jmail  the exception is : **java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1**

Comment: @user3222718 checkm y answer..let me know if you dont understand something

Comment: @user3222718 Are you using AUTO INCREMENT for id in database.

Comment: then **how did pass the value**, I've still saying your Mysql query is wrong, you should change that like my query. And then here also passing id

Answer (score 0):

ok you can try this

before executing this line

```
public void insertClient(int id) {    
        try{
            conn=dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(id,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)select * from register");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

add this to it

```
 String x=null;
 Resultset rs=conn.prepareStatement("select id from old_table where FirstName='request.getParameter('firstname')'and LastName='request.getParameter('lastname')'.......and so on.
while(rs.next){
x=rs.getString('id');
}
```

then use this x and pass it in your insert statement..

Comment: x is the id from the old table..isnt that what you wanted?make another column in your new one for the new id.Or else i would suggest you not to make columns on the new table for firstname,last name...etc.instead just make one column for id.and pass the id from the old table to this new table instead of passing everything..Read more about foreign keys

Comment: thnx for explaination..would not have explained better

Comment: @Santino 'Sonny' Corleone Thank u for that wonderful explaination.. I got your point

Comment: @user211 i got your point but wat am supposed to do it is when i click the approve hyperlink it should fetch the id and only that particular row must be added to login... am supposed to do this.. Its function specific.. Not manually push whatever is in the old table...Did you get my point??

Comment: first of all is the table in d form??

Comment: u need a form to send values from jsp to servlet...u need forms to send data ...I will give u an example..try system.out on the`request.getParameter("id");` and tell me what u get..

Comment: @user211 its displaying the id number

Comment: @user3222718 really???without a form...dats odd..ok since u getting the id now whats the problem?do as santino said.pass oly the id in the new table,instead of all records.u will avoid duplicacy in the database.let me know still if u having problem

Comment: @user3222718 dat answers your question`How to get id from jsp page to servlet? ` since u said you got system.out the id on the servlet.

Comment: ya i know.... thank u anyways.... id is getting passed but what exact output i was expecting thats not happening.... anyways thanks a ton @User211 you really thought me sooo many things thanks

Comment: @user3222718 we need to get the answer for this..wat u want it to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to put them into session or in cookies, if there is only one or two values.

```
session.setAttribute("id",id);
cookie.setAttribute("name",name);
```